# creating an looping audio

Tags: android, loops, audio

Hey I am trying to learn the audio part of android. What I am setting out to do is simple. I want to play one audio file for a half second and then play the second. After the second one ends I want to keep looping between the two. Like I said I am just trying to learn this and I cannot find a decent tutorial. Any help would be great. 
JG

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer rMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.r);
    final MediaPlayer cMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.c);


    Button rockSong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    Button classSong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
    Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3); 

    final TextView rock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView classical = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);





    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            rMusic.seekTo(500);
            rMusic.start();
                if(rMusic.getDuration()==500);
                cMusic.start();
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify, you want play r-file (0.5 sec) then c-file (fully), then r-file (0.5 sec) and s.o.?